# Install alongside windows option ubuntu 18.04 low swap

Tags: 18.04, swap

I have a ThinkPad P1 with 64GB ram. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04, and selected install alongside windows option to leave Ubuntu to handle everything during the installation on 1TB SSD which I have allocated 450GB to Ubuntu.

Once installation completed, I have checked the system and noticed ubuntu only gave 2GB to the swaps partition.

I was wondering if this is normal. What if the system requires more SWAPS, what would happen then?

Thx

Comment: It's okay.

With the memory that you have, you should not have problems.
On my desktop I have a Linux and 32GB of memory I do not have a swap.
If I ever run a mathematical procedure that requires a lot of memory I would create a swapfile to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 17.04 it make a swap file of 2 GB by default. (not a partition)
[image]

You can resize the swap file by following this: https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is it possible to resize the swap? or if the system requires more space, will this get resized automatically?

Comment: Sorry i just remember that Ubuntu 18.04 does not create a swap partition by default. It create a swap file. The system can't resize automatically the swap.

Answer (score 0):

I have only 16 GB ram in my main PC.
I constantly monitor the system with gkrellm and it almost never uses swap.
It is always stressed at 90+% cpu active time (8 core processor) and still does not use swap.

Unless you really feel that a larger swap is necessary (and that would only be if monitoring shows it is filling the swap) I believe there is no need to change the default.

My suggestion -- monitor before you stress out and make changes.